# Split an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsobject

Quick question. I need to split an NSString, if it contains a certain substring. Can someone show me an example of how to do this?

```
// good string
string = RESULT: 123.23

// bad string (has no result prefix)
string = asldkfjasdlkfj

if( string has "RESULT: " in it )
{
   string2 = (something that returns the 123.23 part)
}
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: What have you tried? It doesn't seem like anything, since you're not even writing Objective-C but just some pseudo-language. Apple Developer docs are a great resource, please use them.

Comment: Honestly I haven't tried anything, I just got a bug report on one my iPhone apps, and having a bit longer at work, I was hoping I'd get a quick snippet so when I run home I can submit a patch to apple asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright then, two quick methods:

```
-[NSString hasPrefix:]
-[NSString substringFromIndex:]
```

However don't forget to handle invalid cases.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to split a NSString is:

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator;
```

I hope you found it usefull

Comment: Man, this question is more than a year old!

Comment: Yeah! I know, but I guess that's the solution your looking for. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSString *)splitString {
    NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:@"RESULT: "];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        return [myString substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(range)];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

*Edited to return suffix, not prefix*

Comment: substringFromIndex: range.location+range.length ;)

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you wanted the prefix, but you're right, it was the suffix that was requested. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For even greater flexibility, you could try [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s.